# Numpy shape is same, mean returns different shapes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following snippet.

```
values = [[0.1, 0.7, 0.5], [0.6, 0.3, 0.2], [0.2, 0.8, 0.77]]
A = np.array(values).reshape(3,3)
print A.shape
print np.mean(A, axis=1)

B = np.mat(np.random.rand(3, 3));
print B.shape
print np.mean(B, axis=1)
```

Output of print statements:

```
(3, 3)
[ 0.43333333  0.36666667  0.59      ]

(3, 3)
[[ 0.47252016]
 [ 0.44380355]
 [ 0.51070646]]
```

I have two same shaped numpy array's with different values as an input, one is generated with the `rand` function the other is a python list created with the `array` function and calling reshape on it.

However, the shape of the mean return's a different shape for both, even though the input shapes are the same. Any Ideas what can cause this?

Comment: That absolutely does, just figured out going over it... thanks, that explains it!

Comment: Many of the functions/methods that take an `axis` parameter also take a `keepdims` parameter.  If `True`, it can make the array mean behave more like the matrix one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the documentation for [`numpy.matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html),

> A matrix is a specialized 2-D array that retains its 2-D nature through operations

Additionally,

> It is no longer recommended to use this class, even for linear algebra. Instead use regular arrays. The class may be removed in the future.